# Mailkit Fetch returns unexpected result

Tags: mailkit

I am running in the following issue with MailKit. My Email Client application is in Idle(Inbox). I am adding a new email from Outlook in the Inbox and I receive CountChanged event in my client(MailKit). Inside CountChanged Event I execute

```
remoteFolder.Fetch(messagesCount, -1, MessageSummaryItems.All | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId);
//where messagesCount == 467
```

I have a breakpoint on this line and while I am on the breakpoint, I am switching to Outlook and I delete random email from the Inbox.

After that I am running the line above. I expect Fetch to return 1 email and MessageExpunge event immediatelly after, but what happens is that Fetch returns 2 emails - with UID 468 and 464. The one with UID 464 doesn't have Envelope property set. I would like to know if this is how MailKit Fetch function is supposed to work? Should I filter the result set of Fetch command with
.Where(mailMessage.Index > messagesCount) to get only the new messages?

This below is the server log

```
C: A00000045 IDLE
S: + idling
S: * 468 EXISTS
C: DONE
S: A00000045 OK Idle completed (24.713 + 24.713 + 24.712 secs).
C: A00000046 FETCH 468:* (UID FLAGS INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE ENVELOPE)
S: * 468 FETCH (UID 20873 FLAGS (\Flagged \Seen) INTERNALDATE "25-Aug-2017 16:58:02 +0300" RFC822.SIZE 9648 ENVELOPE ("Fri, 25 Aug 2017 16:57:08 +0300" "Reset Your Zeplin Password" (("Zeplin" NIL "no-reply" "zeplin.io")) (("Zeplin" NIL "no-reply" "zeplin.io")) (("Zeplin" NIL "no-reply" "zeplin.io")) ((NIL NIL "emil.kalchev" "mobisystems.com")) NIL NIL NIL "<30339184.20170825135708.59a02cb4bee526.36618240@mail179-24.suw41.mandrillapp.com>"))
S: * 464 FETCH (MODSEQ (19343) FLAGS (\Flagged \Deleted \Seen))
S: A00000046 OK Fetch completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
C: A00000047 IDLE
S: + idling
S: * 464 EXPUNGE
```

I did a research on https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-73 and indeed by specification imap server can return "unilateral server decision (e.g.,
flag updates)" in FETCH response.

However I wonder why Mailkit doesn't raise MessageFlagChanged event for UID 464

Comment: It's hard to emit the event because the imap server can break the info over multiple untagged FETCH responses. The only way to do it would be to iterate over all items once the FETCH is completed but that can be expensive if there are a lot of messages.

Comment: To answer your question: yea, it's the "expected" behavior but I can see why you were not expecting that. I should probably document that caveat.